# Ajax requests to load content while scrolling page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried and searched but didn't find... How can I change the following method that I wrote to work with the on() method?

```
//Get old posts when scrolling down
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()==($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
    //Get older posts
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/getoldposts.php',
        success: function(oldposts){
            //Append #postsDiv
            $('#postsDiv').append(oldposts);
        }
    });
  } 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

UPDATE 1

I changed the code to the following, but then things that are created on the fly don't have functionality - am I missing some static reference?

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()==($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
    //Get older posts
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/getoldposts.php',
        success: function(oldposts){
            //Append #postsDiv
            $('#postsDiv').append(oldposts);
        }
    });
  } 
});
```

UPDATE 2

On the fly created elements miss the following functionality:

```
$('#postsDiv').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

The method comment() looks as follows:

```
//Function to comment on a post
function comment(commenttext)
{
//Get postid
var commenttextid=commenttext.attr('id');
var postid=commenttextid.replace("commenttext", "");

//Get commenttext
var commenttext=$('#commenttext'+postid).val();

//Ajax of commenttext is not empty
if(commenttext!="")
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/comment.php',
        data: 'commenttext='+commenttext+'&postid='+postid,
        success: function(data){

            //Prepend comments
            $('#comments'+postid).hide().prepend(
                '<div class="comment"><hr/>'+commenttext.replace( /\n/g, '<br/>' )+'</div'
            ).fadeIn('slow');

            //Remove from textarea what was typed in
            $('#commenttext'+postid).val('');

            //Focus on textarea
            $('#commenttext'+postid).focus();
        }
    }).error(function(){
        alert('The comment could not be sent - please try again later.');
    });
}
else
{
    //If the commenttext is empty, focus on the textarea nonetheless
    $('#commenttext'+postid).focus();
}
}
```

The comment gets appended to the newly loaded content but apparently missed the ajax as when I reload the page it is not there anymore.

Comment: `$(window).on("scroll", function(event) { ... });`

Comment: What kind of functionality the things do not have?

Comment: @VisioN The newly loaded content has text areas where on enter the user should be able to submit text (commenting on the new content) - please also see question edit 2

Comment: @VisioN Do you have any idea? Do I maybe lack a selector in the on() method?

Comment: You must add the functionality again to all $('#postsDiv') objects after you added the newly loaded content. Because it only applies the functionality to the currently loaded divs

Comment: @Wezelkrozum Yes but how do I do that?

Comment: @Wezelkrozum Maybe I also need to append the new posts using on?

Comment: Well just remove all the functionalities and apply them again.
$('#postsDiv').off('keydown'); And then the code u used before to add the functionalities $('#postsDiv').on(...

Comment: @Wezelkrozum Could you please show me where in the code you would do that and how you would do it? Thanks!

Comment: I added a piece of code under point 2) in my answere.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10922/discussion-between-dennis-and-wezelkrozum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I've made a similar piece of code a few days ago. Here I assign the page scrolling event to a function which checks how much pixels the user is away from the bottom. If the user has 300 or less pixels less the loadMoreArticles() function is triggered:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
        if(($(document).height()-$(window).height()-$(document).scrollTop()) < 300){
            console.log('Scrolled to bottom');
            ArticleList.loadMoreArticles();
        } else {
            console.log('Scroll '+$(document).height()+' - '+$(window).height()+' - ' +$(document).scrollTop());
        }
    });
```

The console.log() functions shows you it's implemented in the right way

2) You can add the functionalities again after you've appended the new content. Like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()==($(document).height()-$(window).height())){
    //Get older posts
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'action/getoldposts.php',
        success: function(oldposts){
            //Append #postsDiv
            $('#postsDiv').append(oldposts);
            //Remove all functionalities
            $('#postsDiv').off('keydown');
            //Add all functionalities again
            $('#postsDiv').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
                if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
                    comment($(this));
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: @Wezelkrozum Thanks, that's very good because I was still looking for a way to load new content shortly before reaching the end of the window! I am still new to jQuery and curious: what does the console.log() do?

Comment: My suggestion for something like would to have a hidden element at the "end". If this is x % away from top of screen, add more articles.

Comment: When you're viewing your webpage in Chrome you can press CTRL+SHIFT+J and it opens the developers console. Click on Console and you can view all messages javascript produces with the console.log() command. It's a perfect way to debug javascript code. But watch out! In IE the console.log() command stops javascript from running if the developer tools are not visible. U can show them by pressing F12.

Btw, the webpage I've build it in is http://portfolio.wezelkrozum.nl

Answer (score -3):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){ 
// ...
});
```

Comment: What doesn't have functionality? Anything you load via ajax will not have jquery events, etc, bound to them unless you use the .on() method to attach them.

Comment: The newly loaded content doesn't have functionality. I am loading posts that people should be able to comment on even if they were created on the fly. I use the ajax in the on() method so I wonder why they still lack functionality...

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Then the user cannot comment on anything anymore.