# Scrolling by using jQuery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, scroll

Anybody could give me a good example of loading messages from a database using the famous scrolling-down thing using jQuery and PHP?

Comment: Do you mean infinite scrolling?

Comment: possible duplicarte of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466595/ajax-requests-to-load-content-while-scrolling-page

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is "infinite scrolling". There are a whole lot of scripts that implement this functionality. Here are some, if you're using jQuery:

- http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
- http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html
- http://jscroll.com/

Comment: Thanks Filippos for your help...it seems my question finally was a 'real question'... :-)